# radiobuttons on windows phone applicationbar?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, application-bar

Hey guys I have this page :

[image]

PS: this is temp data, so it don't look so good ;P

Now if I click on that filter button, I want a popup window or radio buttons to show in the application bar, is that even possible? Or should I try another way of doing this?

As you choose a radio button I am going to have the page filter on the choice made, so I can't leave the page to go make a choice. Any help/link/tutorial will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,

Working on windows phone 8/ silverlight / c# ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a radio button in the app bar.

I **would** implement this as a separate page and update your filter when you navigate back to this page. The page instance and view model will be still in memory so it should be a matter of detecting the back navigation in OnNavigatedTo and applying your filter at that point. Sharing a ViewModel between this page and your filter page would be the best way of communicating the filter value, but that's not the only way.

Comment: thanks for the insightful reply, one more question? isnt there mayb a way i canmake that page like a type of popup using a grid with a few radiobuttons in?

Comment: You can just use a PhoneApplicationPage and simply have a StackPanel of radio buttons in it (with a title as you choose). You could use the Popup primitive but it would actually be more work as you'd need to create a child control as well as managing position of the child control.